# in wso2 esb what is the function of the below header mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

What is the function of the below header mediator placed after payload factory. What does the name action specify, and is the header mediator placed to append header for request or what?

```
<payloadFactory media-type="xml">
<format>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/
soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.samples">
<soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<ser:getSimpleQuote>
<ser:symbol>$1</ser:symbol>
</ser:getSimpleQuote>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
</format>
<args>
<arg evaluator="json" expression="$.getFinancialQuote.
company"></arg>
</args>
</payloadFactory>
<header name="Action" value="urn:getSimpleQuote"></header>
<call>
<endpoint> <!-- [3] -->
<address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/
SimpleStockQuoteService" format="soap11">
</address>
</endpoint>
</call>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header mediator is placed there to append "action" header for the request to the backend (http://localhost:9000/services/).

This is required by the [backend](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse/blob/master/modules/samples/services/SimpleStockQuoteService/wsdl/SimpleStockQuoteService.wsdl#L196).

Answer (score 0):

This is to set the Action header which is required by the backend. Action header is required by SOAP services to direct to the operation of the service. The header value contains the name of the SOAP operation.